The Laplacian of Kähler potential on a complex-$1$-dimensional Kähler manifold $M$ must be $2$
I am reading comparison geometry of holomorphic bisectional curvature for Kähler manifolds and limit spaces by John Lott. I have encountered a problem, but if my argument below is correct, then the problem has been solved.
Denote by $\omega$ the foundational $2$-form on $M$. Since $M$ is complex-$1$-dimensional, $\omega$ can be written as
$$\omega=\frac{i}2 fdz\wedge d\bar z$$
for some real function $f$. Let $\phi$ be the Kähler potential, that is $\omega=i\partial\bar\partial\phi$, then
$$\frac{i}2 fdz\wedge d\bar z=\omega=i\partial\bar\partial\phi=i\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}dz\wedge d\bar z,$$
so
$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}=\frac f2.$$
Recall that the Laplacian on a Kähler manifold is defined as
$$\Delta f=4 h^{\alpha \bar{\beta}} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial z^{\alpha} \partial \bar{z}^{\beta}} .$$
Therefore,
$$\Delta\phi=4\frac1f\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}=2.$$
Is this valid? Did I make mistakes in my argument? Any help would be appreciated!

You don't say what "the problem" encountered is exactly, but if you're asking "On a complex curve, is the trace of a Kahler form with respect to itself equal to the complex Laplacian of the Kahler potential?", then yes and your argument is good.

We can even do more:
Lemma. The Laplacian of Kaehler potential on a $n$-dimensional Kaehler manifold $M$ is $2n$.
Proof. The Kaehler form $\omega$ can be written as
$$\omega=\sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar j}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j.$$
Let $\phi$ be the Kaehler potential, that is $\omega=\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar\partial\phi$, then
$$\sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar j}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j=\omega=\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar\partial\phi=\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j,$$
so
$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j}=g_{i\bar j}.$$
Recall that the Laplacian on a Kaehler manifold is defined as
$$\Delta f=2g^{i\bar j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j} .$$
Therefore,
$$\Delta\phi=2g^{i\bar j}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j}=2g^{i\bar j}g_{i\bar j}=2n.$$
